# How to use CausalImpact in R to construct an interrupted time series model with >2 periods of interest?

Tags: r, time-series, causalimpact

I would like to conduct an interrupted time series analysis on data with three time periods:

- Pre intervention
- During intervention
- Post intervention

My outcome variable is a continuous biological measurement recorded every second for approx. 48 hours.

I found the CausalImpact package and was able to fit a model with the first two periods (Pre and During), but when I attempted to add a third period, the model would not run:

```
pre.period <- c(0, 293)
during.period <- c(294, 395)
post.period <- c(396, 533)

impact <- CausalImpact(data, pre.period, during.period, post.period)
```

The error message: **Error: args is not a list or args is not NULL**

Basically, I want to know whether the effect of the intervention was sustained during the post intervention period using the during intervention period as the control. Is this not possible or advisable? Should I run a separate analysis comparing during to post? If so, would this introduce a multiple comparisons issue?

I did some research and was able to find a [Stata program](https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/10.1177/1536867X1501500208) (`itsa` command) that appears to be what I'm looking for, but I am not a Stata user. I have yet to find an analogous R program. I would appreciate it if someone could point me in the right direction. Thanks.

Comment: The non-cumulative effect that CI returns varies by time. What do you think about collapsing during and post periods into one for the purpose of analysis, and then comparing how the effect behaves in the two sections of the new combined post period? I have seen this done in advertising experiments where the post period has ads turned off and you are measuring how long the effects take to fade out.